# If the inter-arrival times of customers are i.i.d. exponential distribution, is it necessary that the number of customers is a Poisson process?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-process, queueing-theory

Suppose customers arrive with time interval $U_i$ i.i.d. $Exp(\lambda)$, therefore,

$$F(U_i\le t)=1-e^{-\lambda t}$$

The arrival time of customer $i$ is

$$T_i=\sum^i_{j=1}{U_j}$$

The number of customers having arrived by time $t$ is therefore

$$N(t)=\sum^\infty_{i=1}{1_{\{T_i\le t\}}}$$

$N(t)$ is a counting process.

$N(t)$ is said to be a Poisson counting process if it has the [three properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Interpreted_as_a_counting_process).

This condition seems to imply that i.i.d. exponentially-distributed inter-arrival time doesn't guarantee it is a Poisson process unless it satisfies the four properties.

1. Is i.i.d. exponentially-distributed inter-arrival time a
   necessary and sufficient condition that it is a Poisson process?
2. Does this mean the probability distribution of $N(t)$ is not
   unique or tractable without assumptions such as the three properties?
3. If 1 is true, is there any other possible process besides
   Poisson to formulate $N(t)$?

Comment: "If the inter-arrival times of customers are i.i.d. exponential distribution, is it necessary that the number of customers is a Poisson process?" Yes.

Comment: What you describe is a *homogeneous* Poisson point process.

Comment: @drhab Thanks for pointing out, I just updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative definition of Poisson$(\lambda)$ process is 
\begin{equation}
N(t) = \begin{cases}
               0, X_1>t\\
\sup\{n:X_1 + X_2 + ... +X_n \leq t, X_1\leq t\}
            \end{cases} .
\end{equation}
where $(X_i)_{i=1,2,...}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables, each from $exp(\lambda)$.

This definition directly points out that the process that you defined is without a doubt a Poisson process.

If the process starts in $0$ and has i.i.d. exponentially-distributed inter-arrival time then it is a Poisson process.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Does this mean the properties that Poisson process have are actually inherited from the properties of r.v.'s i.i.d. exponential distribution?

Comment: Yes, we can think of it in this way.